# Defining a String array in XML vs building it dynamically

Tags: android, arrays, string, performance

I am tryin to build a String array of 60 Strings but I am not sure which one is better for performance:

In code dynamically:

```
minuteValues = new String[60];

String minutesBefore = getResources().getString(R.string.minutes_before);

for (int i = 0; i < 60; ++i) {
    minuteValues[i] = i + 1 + minutesBefore;
}
```

or in XML statically:

```
<array name="minutes_before_array">
    <item>1 minute before</item>
    <item>2 minutes before</item>
    <item>3 minutes before</item>
    <item>4 minutes before</item>
    <item>5 minutes before</item>
    .
    .
    .
    <item>60 minutes before</item>
</array>
```

Comment: What is the point of this? Java has a `DateUtil` library that might help you

Comment: Why down grade people? This is a valid question and getiing some good answers. What is the problem?

Comment: What performance metric do you want help with?

Comment: I am trying to reduce requried time to build an object. I was generating the string array in constructor.

Comment: What makes you concerned about creating only 60 Objects? What makes your concerned with them being Strings?

Comment: That famous quote by Donald Knuth seems applicable here. "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." There probably won't be any big difference in this case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no significant performance difference whatsoever.

Here is a cleaner way of doing it, though:

```
<string name="minutes_before">%d minutes before</string>
```

and to use it in your code:

```
int minutes = getNumberOfMinutesSomehow();
String timeString = getResources().getString(R.string.minutes_before, minutes);
```

This uses [the alternate version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString(int, java.lang.Object...)) of `getString`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only the number which changes you can use the plural tag

```
<plural name="minutes_before">
  <item quantity="one">"%1$d minute before"</item>
  <item quantity="other">"%1$d minutes before"</item>
</plural>
```

More [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

Forget performance, building it in code is simply wrong since it is not properly translatable.

Some languages will need to translate "x minutes before" into "minutes x before", and as you have already seen, not all numbers use the same suffix string - in English you have to use a different string for 1 compared to 2, but in other languages then other numbers need different strings.

Comment: I do not need globalization.

Comment: Because you are talking about only 60 Strings. These are not complex objects. These are simple objects to create.

Comment: If you had complex objects that take a lot of extra resources, then you would be more concerned

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a combination of both, use xml resource for future globalization.

XML values in strings.xml

```
//use string resource for globalization
<string name="minute">1 minute before</string>
<string name="minutes">{MIN_TOKEN} minutes before</string>
```

CODE

```
minuteValues = new String[60];

//load single minute text globalized
minuteValues[0] = getResources().getString(R.string.minute);

//load multiple minute text globalized
String minutes = getResources().getString(R.string.minutes);

for (int i = 1; i < 60; ++i) {
    //replace token with numeric value
    minuteValues[i] = minutes.replace("{MIN_TOKEN}", i + 1);
}
```